# 1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict, 3 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector

Tags: kubernetes, redis, persistent-volume-claims, statefulset

I am trying to configure a redis statefulset on a specific node_pool, but when I apply the manifest, I get the following error.

```
0/4 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict, 3 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector.
```

My GKE is Regional and I create a nodepool with one replica in one zone, because it is sufficient for the redis work.

The node_pool is in a single zone. My idea is that the 3 replicas live inside that particular node.

How can I configure that the 3 PVCs are in the same node_pool?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: redis
spec:
  serviceName: redis
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: config
        image: redis:6.2.3-alpine
        command: [ "sh", "-c" ]
        args:
          - |
            cp /tmp/redis/redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf
            
            echo "finding master..."
            MASTER_FDQN=`hostname  -f | sed -e 's/redis-[0-9]\./redis-0./'`
            if [ "$(redis-cli -h sentinel -p 5000 ping)" != "PONG" ]; then
              echo "master not found, defaulting to redis-0"
              if [ "$(hostname)" == "redis-0" ]; then
                echo "this is redis-0, not updating config..."
              else
                echo "updating redis.conf..."
                echo "slaveof $MASTER_FDQN 6379" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
              fi
            else
              echo "sentinel found, finding master"
              MASTER="$(redis-cli -h sentinel -p 5000 sentinel get-master-addr-by-name mymaster | grep -E '(^redis-\d{1,})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})')"
              echo "master found : $MASTER, updating redis.conf"
              echo "slaveof $MASTER 6379" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
            fi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: redis-config
          mountPath: /etc/redis/
        - name: config
          mountPath: /tmp/redis/
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:6.2.3-alpine
        command: ["redis-server"]
        args: ["/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data
        - name: redis-config
          mountPath: /etc/redis/
      volumes:
      - name: redis-config
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: redis-config
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: redis-pool
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "standard"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: redis
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
    name: redis
  selector:
    app: redis
```

Comment: Please check the resources of the nodes

Comment: May I ask, why would you like to have 3 instances on the same node? Couldn’t you use a single instance in that case?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. 
@NatarajMedayhal the nodes is empty, just the kubernetes config pods.

Comment: @Jonas you mean of using a VM instead of raising the redis in the kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Can you ensure that the nodes in your node_pool have the label `redis-pool`? From your requirements, you should only have 1 node with this label, which will allow all 3 replicas to be scheduled to this node.

And it is not technically correct to say `PVCs in the same node_pool`. You are using the `storageClass: default` in your PVC template, this will cause your `PersistentVolumeClaims` to be backed by `Google Persistent Disks (GPDs)`. Which are separate from your node_pools (compute resource) and should not be considered part of the compute infrastructure.

They belong to the storage part of your GCloud. The GKE however handles the connection between the storage and compute transparently to you, so it doesn't feel like you're using the GPDs, but it is important to understand this distinction.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I found a solution, i create a StorageClass with a "matchLabelExpressions" matching a specific zone, so I define to use that StorageClass on my StafefulSet manifest matching the StorageClass name to "data"

Statefulset

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: redis
spec:
  serviceName: redis
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: config
        image: redis:6.2.3-alpine
        command: [ "sh", "-c" ]
        args:
          - |
            cp /tmp/redis/redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf
            
            echo "finding master..."
            MASTER_FDQN=`hostname  -f | sed -e 's/redis-[0-9]\./redis-0./'`
            if [ "$(redis-cli -h sentinel -p 5000 ping)" != "PONG" ]; then
              echo "master not found, defaulting to redis-0"
              if [ "$(hostname)" == "redis-0" ]; then
                echo "this is redis-0, not updating config..."
              else
                echo "updating redis.conf..."
                echo "slaveof $MASTER_FDQN 6379" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
              fi
            else
              echo "sentinel found, finding master"
              MASTER="$(redis-cli -h sentinel -p 5000 sentinel get-master-addr-by-name mymaster | grep -E '(^redis-\d{1,})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})')"
              echo "master found : $MASTER, updating redis.conf"
              echo "slaveof $MASTER 6379" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
            fi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: redis-config
          mountPath: /etc/redis/
        - name: config
          mountPath: /tmp/redis/
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:6.2.3-alpine
        command: ["redis-server"]
        args: ["/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data
        - name: redis-config
          mountPath: /etc/redis/
      volumes:
      - name: redis-config
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: redis-config
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: redis-pool
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "data"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Mi
```

StorageClass

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: data
  namespace: redis
provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  replication-type: none
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: topology.gke.io/zone
    values:
    - europe-west3-a
```